# How to fix trix editor in laravel 5.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, laravel-5.8, trix

I am trying to add trix editor in a form. It appears but the toolbar is disabled its not working. After some research i found that  was in the header of my layout file so i moved it in the end of the body and removed "defer" and now trix editor is disappeared.

layout file

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>   
 @yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

field where i want trix editor

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="content">Content</label>
   <input id="content" type="hidden" name="content">
   <trix-editor input="content"></trix-editor>
</div>
```

trix js and css

```
@section('scripts')
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.1.1/trix.js"></script>
@endsection

@section('css')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.1.1/trix.css">
@endsection
```

Comment: I tried to clean up the code formatting a bit. Please make sure there's enough information here so that someone can use the code you've posted to recreate your issue so that they can help you figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--> composer require te7a-houdini/laravel-trix

--> php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Te7aHoudini\LaravelTrix\LaravelTrixServiceProvider"

--> php artisan migrate

In your page use like

```
<html>
    <head>
        @trixassets
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="route('article.store')">
            @csrf
            @trix(\App\Article::class, 'content')
            <input type="submit">
        </form>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i made demo trix editor and it's working fine in laravel 5.8.14 v

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.1.1/trix.css">
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #636b6f;
                font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 200;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .full-height {
                height: 100vh;
            }

            .flex-center {
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .position-ref {
                position: relative;
            }

            .top-right {
                position: absolute;
                right: 10px;
                top: 18px;
            }

            .content {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .title {
                font-size: 84px;
            }

            .links > a {
                color: #636b6f;
                padding: 0 25px;
                font-size: 13px;
                font-weight: 600;
                letter-spacing: .1rem;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            .m-b-md {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="top-right links">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                        @endif
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Laravel
                </div>
                 <trix-editor input="content"></trix-editor>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.1.1/trix.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Did you forget to add jquery ?

[image: t Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The link of js of trix code that you have mentioned in your `section('scripts')`, instead of including in 'scripts' section. Directly paste the link in your main HEAD section of html, may be its in layouts.app.

or you can also do the same as you have done but just change some code as like:

1. In your html, head section, add yield as like `@YIELD('CSCRIPTS')` just below other mentioned SCRIPT tag, make sure you use new name in yield.
2. In html, head section, you will also see other SCRIPT tag, there remove DEFER if it is there.
3. And finally, go to the blade where your SECTION belong and change it to `@SECTION('CSCRIPTS')`.
4. Works well.

But also you will see the other script tag, there and remove DEFER keyword.
Other keep as it, works perfectly